# Difficulty Generating Refresh Token in Akeneo OAuth2 Integration

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, akeneo, oauth-refresh-token

I have been actively working on the integration of Akeneo with my custom application, and I've encountered a challenge related to the refresh token. While Akeneo's official documentation provides extensive guidance on generating access tokens for OAuth2, it notably lacks information regarding the inclusion of a refresh token in the response.

Here's a summary of my experience:

**Access Token**: Following the official documentation's instructions, I can generate access tokens for OAuth2 without an issue.

**Refresh Token**: However, the documentation does not specify how to obtain a refresh token, and my attempts to do so have been fruitless.

I've conducted a thorough search, both within the documentation and through online resources, but my efforts to find a method for generating a refresh token for OAuth within the Akeneo API have proven unsuccessful.

I've even tried exploring alternative approaches, such as adopting the OpenID Connect method, which does provide a refresh token in response. Nevertheless, I'm still unable to figure out how to generate a refresh token while using OAuth for Akeneo.

I need to find the refresh token the OAuth way.

I kindly request the community's assistance in shedding light on this issue. If anyone has successfully tackled the challenge of generating a refresh token in the context of Akeneo OAuth2 integration, please share your insights or direct me to any relevant resources. Your guidance will be greatly appreciated, and it will help me move forward with this integration successfully.

Thank you in advance for your assistance in resolving this matter.